# "what's to stop something" and the "be+to+verb" construction

Tags: meaning

I was reading an article and there was a line that has *what's to stop*:

> If the Big Tech oligarchs can muzzle the former President, what's to stop them from silencing you?

What does *"What's to stop"* mean here? It seems to be of the form of *"be + to + verb"* construction. As per the explanation from [Collins Dictionary](https://grammar.collinsdictionary.com/us/easy-learning/how-do-you-use-be-to-verb-to-talk-about-the-future-in-english), *"Be + to + Verb"* can be used to talk about the plans in the future, or to give instructions or commands.

Does it convey the same meaning as *"What could stop them from silencing you"* or *"What will stop them from silencing you"*?

Comment: 1-It's an idiom. 2-Sounds like my Noo Yawk. 3-It is a common dare ("What's it **too** ya, huh?") and the opposite of formal, as the link suggests.

Comment: It's a shortened form of "what is there to do something". In this case it means "what exists to stop them".

Comment: It is the question form of *there is nothing to stop them* or *there isn't anything to stop them*. It's an imbedded rhetorical question, and yes, an idiom. Note *what's stopping them from ...* is less rhetorical.

Comment: to stop [someone] from doing something is completely idiomatic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'What's to stop them from silencing you' indeed means 'What could possibly stop them from silencing you.'

Though probably best treated as a fixed expression, and looking at possibility (however slight),

(*What's to stop me/you/her/them/it/the Government ... from Ving* ...) (but often fronted by 'What's', not usually by say 'John's')

*does* seem related to the more general 'be to do something' (conveying a command):

*He's/You're to stop them from leaving even if it means he needs/you need  to lock them in their room!*

Interestingly, we now need a volitional agent, while 'What's ...?' doesn't, and even strongly suggests a non-volitional agent. Though of course 'Who's' could also be used.

The 'purpose' sense of 'be to V' doesn't need a volitional agent:

*The handcuffs are to stop him from resisting*

but this is a different sense.

Comment: I read the meaning of the phrase more like what Phil Sweet said in his comment on the question. But the rest of the answer is spot on.